Issue logging out from Duende Identity Server 7 from Maui Client
I used the sample client for Duende hosted at
https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/tree/main/various/clients/Maui
Using the Android Emulator, I was able to successfully login, but when I attempt to logout I get redirected to a browser with a blank page at my authority URL.
I then attempted to open the URL in Chrome and this was URL that was being loaded.
https://dev.amnathrig.app/Home but nothing is configured at the URL.
This is the code I used to logout where _client is an instance of IdentityModel.OidcClient.OidcClient
MessageLabel.Text = "Logging out...";

var result = await _client.LogoutAsync();

if (result.IsError)
{
    MessageLabel.Text = $"Logout Error: {result.Error}";
    return;
}

This is my client configuration in the mobile application
// setup OidcClient
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new OidcClient(new()
{
    Authority = "https://dev.amnathrig.app",

    ClientId = "maui_client",
    Scope = "openid profile amnathrigAPI",
    RedirectUri = "amnathrig://callback",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "amnathrig://callback", 
    

    Browser = new MauiAuthenticationBrowser()
}));


and this is the the configuration of the client on the server
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "maui_client",
     ClientName = "MAUI App",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
     RequireClientSecret = false,
     RedirectUris = { "amnathrig://callback" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "amnathrig://callback" },
     AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "amnathrigAPI", "roles" },
     AllowOfflineAccess = true,
 }

Any idea why it tries to load the **Home ** page instead of going through the logout flow?
I also tried running without the PostLogoutRedirectURI but I got the error below.
System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI is empty.' when the logout was initiated.

